# Find the value of $k$ in $4x^2+4(k-2)x+k=0$ if the equation has two equal roots.

Tags: functions

> Find the value of $k$ in $4x^2+4(k-2)x+k=0$ if the equation has two equal roots.

Can you help me find the solution to the given problem?

My specific problem was finding out how to create value $b$ for the quadratic equation I'm going to use to solve this problem.

Comment: Just use the given expression as your $b$ value and see when do you get two equal roots.

Answer (score 1):

$b$ is what's multiplying your $x$ term. So $b=4(k-2)=4k-8$.

Then consider the discriminant. Since the equation has a repeated root, $$b^2-4ac=0$$ and hence:
$$(4k-8)^2-4\times4k=0
\\ \implies 16k^2+64-64k-16k=0
\\ \implies 16k^2-80k+64=0
\\ \implies k^2-5k+4=0
\\ \implies (k-1)(k-4)=0
$$
and so $k=1$ or $k=4$.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is the variable for the quadratic equation.  So the value of $b$ (for use in the quadratic formula) is $4(k-2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$4x^2+4(k-2)x+k=0$$

Can you compare this to?

$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

and, for equal roots,

$$b^2-4ac=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Take a general quadratic:

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
We can solve $f(x)=0$ by using the *quadratic equation:*
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Each quadratic has two roots. If those two roots are equal, it must be because $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=0$ (and, as a result, $b^2-4ac=0$). This is because the equation then becomes $$x=\frac{-b\pm0}{2a}=\frac{-b}{2a}$$

In your case, $a=4, b=4(k-2), c=k$, and so you want to solve:
$$4^2(k-2)^2-4(4)(k)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically speaking for a parabola in that family to have a double root it must be tangent to the $x$-axis (which has a straight line of constant derivate $0$). So determine where each parabola in the family attain a derivative of $0$
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[4x^2+4(k-2)x+k\right]=0\\
8x+4(k-2)=0\\
x=-\frac{1}{2}(k-2)
\end{equation}

Then substitute this value of $x$ where a parabola has a zero slope into the equation and solve for $k$
\begin{equation}
(k-2)^2-2(k-2)^2+k=0\\
-(k-2)^2+k=0\\
k^2-5k+4=0\\
k=
\begin{cases}
1\\
4
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Completing the square and comparing gives
$(k-2)^2=k$, hence $k\in\{1,4\}$.